# WPF - Use static resource in multiple windows

Tags: wpf, class-library

I have an application with many Windows, and I want to use the same templates and styles in all of these windows.

**Warning:** This is NOT a "WPF Application", it's a "class library" using WPF windows. I do not have an "App.xaml" file!!!

What is the easiest way to do that in WPF?

Currently, I have this in a Window, working fine:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
        <Grid  ToolTip="{Binding Path=/ErrorContent}">
            ....
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="Control" x:Key="ErrorStyle">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            ... 
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And I use it as

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource ErrorStyle}" .../>
```

But this is clearly declared in a single Window. How do I declare it in a way that it could be used by many windows (considering **I do not have** an `App.xaml` file)

Comment: Regarding your edit, it doesn't matter. You can still use ResourceDictionary and merge them wherever you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the App.Xaml, will be available for all items in the application

Alternatively you can create ResourceDictionaries and merge those in the App.Xaml or anywhere you need them

DOCS:

Application.Resources
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/systems/xaml-resources-how-to-use-application?view=netdesktop-6.0

Merged Dictionaries
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/systems/xaml-resources-merged-dictionaries?view=netdesktop-6.0

Comment: It's generally best to post a brief but helpful example/summary as links can die at any time, which would make a complete answer that only lists external references pretty useless.